# Access to RSS of a private Google Group

Tags: rss, google-groups

I would like to access to a feed RSS of a private Google Group. I'm a user of this group.

I want to build a script that read this RSS and the publish all the new topics to a private and related Telegram channel.

I think it's possible to use some Google Oath authentication, but I do not if I'm right and where to start.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several APIs that allow to interact with the different components of Google Groups there isn't one to access the private RSS feeds.

Regarding where to start looking for Google APIs, the right place is http://developers.google.com